# QGIS Georeferencer returning blank output

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I cannot get QGIS's (2.8.2 Wein/Win 7) georeferencer to work for the life of me. I select points, set the CRS, run the function, 
[image: before]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JoOt.jpg

and the output looks like this.
[image: after]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Nry.png

Blank on the map, set to 0 to 0 in the red band and blank in the others in Layer properties (hitting Load changes these values, but apply does not change the screen and the changes are not maintained after I close the properties window), but a garbled thumbnail of the original image still appears. Zoom to layer does not change the display location. Original image in .jpg.

I've seen bug reports for this (or similar) issue stretching back to 1.8 but never any resolutions. Where am I going wrong?

edit: 
Andre, using your method produced the same result, unfortunately. I cannot seem get a useable image out of the georeferencer, even with adjusting the stretch values, unloading/reloading, et c.

[image: geo]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRmcs.png

[image: map]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8L9R.jpgg

Comment: Have you tried converting the original image to an alternative format, perhaps a tif?  I don't know if it's a bug but it's one thing that I sometimes try when I'm having issues with georeffing images.

Comment: unfortunately reproduced the error using a .tif

Comment: What transformation settings are you using? For two-point georeferencing I normally use Helmert/Linear. This needs a good, undistorted scan or image.

Comment: linear in this example, but i've gone as a high as 15 tie in points with the same results

Answer (score 3):

You only have two GCP points in your list. With that little information, the Georeferencer can not work.

Try to grab as much points as you can identify across the whole picture.

---

**Update**

I was successfull with a part of your screenshot and these settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: my understanding was that two points would work with a linear transformation (see above), but i've also used many more points and other transformations with the same results